# Meaning of #define THIS_

Tags: mesh, d3dx

For example, there is a function named CreateFrame like,

```
virtual STDMETHODIMP CreateFrame(THIS_ LPCSTR Name, 
LPD3DXFRAME*ppNewFrame);
```

I think STDMETHODIMP  means It will return HResult and stdcall function,
but I don't know what THIS_ in argument menas.

THIS_ is defined in combaseapi.h like this.

```
  #define PURE                    = 0
  #define THIS_
  #define THIS                    void
```

For more information, the function 'CreateFrame ' is called automatically when
D3DXLoadMeshHierarchyFromX is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are just old-school COM macros. Don't worry about them, especially since you are looking at the deprecated D3DX header for legacy Direct3D 9 from 13+ years ago...

```
virtual STDMETHODIMP Func(THIS);
```

This is a function that takes *ONE* parameter: the implicit `this` pointer, returns an `HRESULT`, and is annotated for proper COM calling convention `__stdcall`.

```
virtual STDMETHODIMP Func(THIS_ LPCSTR Name, LPD3DXFRAME*ppNewFrame);
```

This is a function that takes *THREE* parameters: the implicit `this` pointer, a pointer to a string, and a pointer to a specific object), returns an `HRESULT`, and is annotated for proper COM calling convention.

To declare a function that returns a type other than `HRESULT` you'd use `STDMETHOD_`:

```
virtual STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Func) (THIS_ LPCSTR Name, LPD3DXFRAME*ppNewFrame);
```

These old headers often also supported use from C rather than C++, where `this` is not implicit. Legacy D3DX never bothered with the C call-paths, but many old system headers did use them. In fact, if you did a little further in `combaseapi.h` you'll see the C language section defines `THIS_` and `THIS` as:

```
#define PURE
#define THIS_                   INTERFACE FAR* This,
#define THIS                    INTERFACE FAR* This
```

The more modern MIDL compiler generates code that's slightly less confusing:

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Func(void);
```

or

```
virtual void STDMETHODCALLTYPE Func(UINT value, LPCWSTR name);
```